# java.lang.StackOverFlowError in android studio

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow, logcat

i am working as a beginner on  new android application, i have done everything according to the tutorials, but im still getting this error.  here is the code for MyAcitivty.java:

this is MYActivity.java

```
 package com.example.ambuj.myfirstapp;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.view.Menu; 
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;


 public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.ambuj.myfirstapp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }




public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void openSearch(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Search Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void openSettings(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Button Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

this is my logcat:

```
            01-18 14:22:33.180  26194-26194/com.example.ambuj.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ambuj.myfirstapp, PID: 26194
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.util.SparseArray.get(SparseArray.java:111)
        at android.util.SparseArray.get(SparseArray.java:102)
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:70)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledString(AssetManager.java:275)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:730)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:97)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:168)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
        at com.example.ambuj.myfirstapp.MyActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MyActivity.java:32)
        at com.example.ambuj.myfirstapp.MyActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MyActivity.java:33)
```

Comment: Without code you'll have to wait for a mind reader to help you. He usually doesn't exist.

Comment: please post the code!!!

Comment: Post the lines 32, 33 of MyActivity.java and whatever else you think necessary

Comment: im sorry guys, i have added the code now, please help

Comment: replace this line return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); with return true;

Comment: @thirteenguy also post your menu.xml and activity_layout.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yout problem is here:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); //<--- conflicting line
}
```

Change

```
return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

to

```
return true;
```

Hope it helps